# Does a Buffered ObjectInputStream exist?

Tags: java, performance, serialization, buffer

I am deserializing an object from a file that is 350KB in size, and its taking rather a long time. My computer science TA told me that there is a way to use a Buffered reader along with the ObjectInputStream to greatly increase performance. I however can not find anything about this on Google.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You use decoration to buffer the input stream. Like this

```
   InputStream in = ...; // your underlying stream (e.g. FileInputStream)
   ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(in));
```

This will ensure that each call to ObjectInputStream does not call the base stream `in`, such as the OS's file read system call. Instead, each call goes to the buffered input stream, which fetches and caches blocks of data (8K by default), and reads from that. This is faster, since reading from the stream is now a local method call in java, and the method call overhead of a system call is encountered less often. Cache coherence and JIT optimizations also come into play in improving performance.

Comment: `ObjectInputStream` uses a 1k buffer at least part of the time, so this suggestion won't have as dramatic an effect as suggested here.

Comment: @EJP Will this solution be efficient enough for reading Objects as well as lines like `readLine()` method in `BufferedReader` does?

Answer (score 2):

No but You can use 
ObjectInputStream(InputStream in) constructor

To create buffered object intput stream by passing BufferedInputStream as argument to above constructor.

Here is example for reading serialized objects from file:

```
InputStream file = null;
try {
   file = new FileInputStream("Out.test");
   InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(file);
   ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(buffer);
   vector = (Vector)in.readObject();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
   if(file != null ) {
       file.close();
   }
}
```

Checkout following link :

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPIOPerformance.fm.html

Comment: Might want a `try {` after the `file` declaration line, and a `} finally { file.close(); }` instead of `in.close();`.

Comment: This code definitely won't compile, since in the `finally` block, `file` isn't declared.

Comment: @uckelman Now code should compile. Earlier I had put in ref code but didn't test/compile same.

Comment: The above mentioned link is no longer active, but it referred to the book "Java Platform Performance: Strategies and Tactics".